# Questions about databases are wrongly marked as db2

Tags: discussion, tags, questions

As a DB2 expert, and one of the top 5 answerers in StackOverFlow-db2, I have faced many question related to general 'SQL' and 'databases'. However, many users do not tagged them correctly, they do not know 'DB2' is a RDBMS, and they just think that 'db' is equals to 'db2', and they leave that tag 'db2'.

I have changed many questions that refers to 'databases', by erasing the 'DB2' tag.

How can it be possible to prevent this error from new users?

Comment: Given that software engineers don't read I'm afraid you have to live with that.... The only thing I could imagine is making the wiki excerpt shorter and SHOUT when NOT to use the tag.... but I have low hopes if that will solve your issue...